# What is the significance of Jack's makeup?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, werewolf-by-night

In *Werewolf by Night*, Jack had a conversation with another monster hunter, Joshua, about Jack's makeup.

> **Joshua:** I like your whole look here with the makeup. It's a killer trademark.
> **Jack:** Yeah. It's to honor my ancestors.
> **Joshua:** Yeah. Not much for honoring ancestors and feelings and all that. I just know it looks brilliant on you.
> I mean, I understand the importance of anonymity in our line of work, but it gets lonely.

Is there a deeper significance to Jack's makeup, or the conversation? A reference to the comic books, perhaps? Or is it just mundane small talk?

Screencaps of Jack's makeup:
[image: screencap][image: screencap]

In werewolf form:
[image]

Comment: Isn't Jack played by Gael García Bernal, a Mexican actor? Perhaps the makeup is not literally Día de Muertos getup, but it seems to trace a skull mask shape around his eyes, so there is some definite resonance.